# Need advices on iOS MVC

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

Based on Apple's document:

[image]

The **View** is never communicating directly with **Model**. Instead it's through the **Controller**.But I have a case which need to customise my UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell.

The customised view is very complicated. If I put all the logic in my view controller. It will become very difficult. Instead if I put the logic thus the model in my view. Then the code will be cleaner. But it disobeys the Apple's MVC principle. My question is how you'll handle this scenario? Is there any elegant way to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/table-views.html) if you have not, should ring a bell.

Comment: Thanks for anybody upvote my question. I'm looking at MVVM and VIPER now. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.